# I'm using numerictextbox in grid. But the data does not bind. Why it is not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I want to put numerictextbox in my kendo grid. So, i decide to use Editor Templates. It's work because when i run it, the numerictextbox appear. However, after i insert some number, the number will show, but if i click anywhere, the number will dissapear as i'm not insert anything.

this is my code in index.

```cs
@(Html.Kendo().Grid((IEnumerable<DDLnetcore.Models.Product>)ViewBag.Product)
                                .Name("grid")
                                .Columns(columns =>
                                {
                                    columns.Bound(p => p.Name).Width(100);
                                    columns.Bound(p => p.Price).EditorTemplateName("Numeric");
                                    columns.Command(command => command.Destroy()).Width(150);
                                })
                                .ToolBar(toolBar =>
                                {
                                    toolBar.Create();
                                    toolBar.Save();
                                })
                                .Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.InCell))
                                .Pageable()
                                .Scrollable()
                                .Sortable()
                                .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:550px;" })
                                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                                    .Ajax()
                                    .Batch(true)
                                    .PageSize(20)
                                    .ServerOperation(false)
                                    .Events(events => events
                                    .Error("errorHandler")
                                    )
                                    .Model(model =>
                                    {
                                        model.Id(p => p.Id);
                                        model.Field(p => p.Price);
                                    })
                                    .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Products"))
                                    .Update(update => update.Action("Buatdata", "Products"))
                                    .Create(create => create.Action("Buatdata", "Products"))
                                    .Destroy(destroy => destroy.Action("Destroy", "Products"))
                               )
    )
```

and this is my editor templates code

```cs
@model DDLnetcore.Models.Product

@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor<decimal>(m => m.Price)
                .Format("c")
                .Min(0)
                .Max(100)
)
```

the code in index already read my editor templates code, because of that the numerictextbox shown. but the data is not bound. is there anything wrong in my code?

Comment: Came here to answer that solution :) It will be good if you answer your question below and set it as accepted answer, instead of editing the original question.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already found the problem. The problem is in my editor templates. For those who have same problem, try change to this code in editor templates.

```
@model decimal

@(Html.Kendo().NumericTextBoxFor<decimal>(m => m)
                            .Format("c")
                            .Min(0)
                            .Max(100)
)
```

Thank you.